# checking char input in c

Tags: c, if-statement, char, logical-or, logical-and

I have a piece of code here :

```
     printf("Enter only parenthesis to arr or anything else to exit\n");
    
     scanf(" %c", &data);

    if (data != '(' || data != ')' || data != '[' ||
        data != ']' || data != '{' || data != '}')
    {
        printf("\nExit scanning \n");
        return;
    }
```

My problem that no matter what i do when I enter any parenthesis it enters the "if" condition. I also tried getchar() but nothing worked either.
Can you tell what's wrong I can't understand

Comment: Your condition is always true. If `data != '('` it is true, otherwise it is '(' and so `data != ')'` is true.

Comment: _My problem that no matter what i do when I enter any parenthesis it enters the "if" condition._ I infer that _if_ you enter `(` you would like the program to _not_ do the `printf/return`. Easy to fix: Change all `||` into `&&` --> `if (data != '(' && data != ')' && data != '[' && data != ']' && data != '{' && data != '}')` OR, use the DeMorgan equivalent expression: `if (! (data == '(' || data == ')' || data == '[' || data == ']' || data == '{' || data == '}'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved simply.

First of all write the condition for which the input must satisfy

```
if (data == '(' || data == ')' || data == '[' ||
    data == ']' || data == '{' || data == '}')
```

Now negate it

```
if ( !( data == '(' || data == ')' || data == '[' ||
        data == ']' || data == '{' || data == '}' ) )
```

and open the parentheses and you will get

```
if (data != '(' && data != ')' && data != '[' &&
    data != ']' && data != '{' && data != '}')
{
    printf("\nExit scanning \n");
    return;
}
```

That is all.

Another approach is to use standard string function `strchr` declared in header `<string.h>` as for example

```
if ( strchr( "()[]{}", data ) == NULL )
{
    printf("\nExit scanning \n");
    return;
}
```

Or if the user can enter the code 0 then

```
if ( data == '\0' || strchr( "()[]{}", data ) == NULL )
{
    printf("\nExit scanning \n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I'd suggest using 'not' operator with "strchr()" as you have shown with the "&&" version. Simple to read `!strchr( ...)` as meaning "not a character in this set of characters."... It is the same thing, but (to me) seems more _natural_... Just a thought...